# .htaccess exception for one folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have this one `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]
```

Now I want to upload separate scripts to the `beta/` folder, what I must change in `.htaccess` for right working script in `beta/` folder separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/beta/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]
```

Comment: It should work... I just add a simple test for `/beta/`. You only use this code, and all the code ? And nothing in `/beta/` which may cause the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to create another `.htaccess` and put it your `beta/` folder. It'd then can override what's "parent" `.htaccess` set.

Comment: But I never access `beta/` folder than as I see.